# How do I save my command snippets for quick access from the commandline?

Tags: ruby, command-line, code-snippets

I have a huge file with all the commands I use on and off the commandline. This file is getting harder to open and navigate as its size gets larger. I am looking for a commandline utility that makes this process easier. I found [this gem](https://github.com/holman/boom), which does something similar to what I want, but it's terrible with long lines of code with multiple quotation marks.

What does everyone use to keep your code snippets and easily access it from your terminal?

Answer (score 4):

I keep a similar file myself. This example isn't directly useful with your file. However when I find that I need to run a particular command I recently used, without looking it up again, I run a grep on history.

For example:

> history | grep "svn co"

Comment: Combined with `export HISTSIZE=<large number>` in your .bashrc to keep history around for longer.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Komandi](https://komandi.app), a multiplatform command snippets manager.